# See the timezone for the scheduled lab?

Tags: azure-lab-services

Whenscheduling a Lab it seems as if the timezone is UTC. While that is fine it would be good if one could schedule in a local timezone and the scheduler could do the math to convert it to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pick the timezone in the schedule ui. See the highlight in the screenshot below. [image: Screen with create schedule]